# How can we set the proxy setting in Azure Application Insights SDK?

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

How can we set the proxy details by using the Azure Application Insights SDK?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the network configuration section in your web.config to set a default proxy for the whole application: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kd3cf2ex(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Thanks for the information but, Is there any way we can use the proxy setting using Application Insights Java SDK? I didn't find any method to set proxy in Application Insights SDK.

Comment: Oh, you're using the Java SDK ok. Can you give me more information about the application you're developing please ?

Comment: I am developing the java standalone application where user may need to provide the proxy details while sending the telemetry data to azure. So can we add proxy details in application insights client?